# gb4e + biblatex error "patching footnotes failed"

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, linguistics, gb4e

I'm having a problem while using `gb4e` and `biblatex` in the same file. It does compile, but I get an "patching footnotes failed" warning.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}

ejemplo de texto


\end{document}
```

Gives the error:

```
 Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
 (biblatex) Footnote detection will not work.
```

Am I doing something wrong? is the warning important or could I just ignore it?

Answer (score 9):

The `gb4e` package redefines `\footnotetext` so that it can deal with examples within footnotes.  `biblatex` detects this change and issues the warning, since it assumes that `\footnotetext` is defined as in the LaTeX kernel.  Footnote detection is only used in *ibid* style referencing schemes, and since you are using an Author-Year scheme there should be no problem for you, and you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: My apologies, Alan. I've already asked a new question ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327711)) but forgot to delete my comment here.