# Beamer patching footnotes warning: "Patching footnotes failed. Footnote detection will not work."

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, warnings

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Foo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will give the warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex) Footnote detection will not work.
```

I read [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/bugs/111/#da50) and in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108523/9953) that the warning can be safely ignored. Can I force `biblatex` to avoid giving the warning altogether?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This warning is issued during package loading as [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) attempts to patch certain commands (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)). So, there's no way of avoiding this message directly without editing a `.sty` file ([`biblatex2.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/biblatex2.sty) in this case) or using alternate means... like the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{silence,lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
% Filter warnings issued by package biblatex starting with "Patching footnotes failed"
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Foo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Versions of `biblatex` starting from 3.10 support patching `beamer`'s footnote commands so that footnote detection works and no warning is issued.

If you still get this warning you should look into updating `biblatex` (and with it Biber).

See also [Beamer and biblatex possible remedy for warning: **Patching footnotes failed**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405186/35864), https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/581 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/5169d2a64777090aa29d38df7543301f5c8b876b

Comment: Would you know why this warning appears on a 2021 updated texlive? I'm `knit`ing an `Rmd` file with `latex_engine: xelatex`, does that matter? Thanks!  Edit: The warning is, to quote "Warning: Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch `footnote' on input line 139."

Comment: @PatrickT Sorry, no. If you can come up with a minimal example document, I can of course investigate, but without one there are just too many unknowns.

Comment: Thanks! @moewe. I'll see how it goes and post a question if it doesn't go away! :-)