# Beamer and biblatex possible remedy for warning: **Patching footnotes failed**

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber, warnings

After reading that the warning, `Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.` is generated due to a redefinition of `\@footnotetext` by **beamer** I tried to retain its definition with the following patch. However, after compiling the document I noticed all my citations in the footnotes were gone. I use `\footcitetext` together with `\footnotemark` to have references in the footnotes.

```
\makeatletter
\let\predefinedfootnotetext\@footnotetext
\makeatother

\documentclass[10pt, xcolor = {dvipsnames}, presentation]{beamer} % xcolor is already loaded with beamer 

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext\predefinedfootnotetext
\makeatother
```

[Beamer patching footnotes warning: "Patching footnotes failed. Footnote detection will not work."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202988/beamer-patching-footnotes-warning-patching-footnotes-failed-footnote-detection)

Such as the above most of the answers on this site suggest using the `silence` package, yet I wonder how to remedy this issue correctly. Some suggest editing the **sty** files, but it seems to be a daunting task.

What is the scope of this problem, when are you bound to run into trouble?

Comment: In most cases the warning is not a problem at all. Only if you use certain `verbose`-type styles or make a distinction between footnote and in-text citation and use other intricate features does it become relevant. In most other cases it can be safely ignored (or silenced).

Comment: @moewe I understood I want to correct it anyhow. How should I proceed then?

Comment: Why though? Do you need it? You will not benefit from a change if you don't use any of the affected features (which is unlikely). You would have to hack the redefinition of footnote in beamer and even then you are probably not done. You would have to have the `biblatex` developers include this in the `biblatex` code.

Comment: @Vesnog If the warning does not cause you any problems, I would not mess with beamer footnotes - they are quite clever, overlay aware and everything, and the only thing you gain is the risk to break nice beamer features...

Comment: @samcarter It should be possible to patch `beamer`'s footnote though. I could almost get it running, but then patching fails because of an incorrect category code regime in `beamer`.

Comment: @samcarter I thought it would be educational for me and I will have a better understanding of Latex after finding out the reason why my style did not work and why this error happens.

Comment: One challenge I found when fixing a similar issue with `bidi` is that you also need to deal with how `hyperref` interacts with footnotes. And you would probably need to take care of interactions with `bidi` too to did things properly.

Comment: My attempts to look at this did not work out, but we have a ticket at the `biblatex` bug tracker for this (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/581). So if there is a solution here that can be implemented in `biblatex`, that would be great.

Answer (score 8):

> Starting from version 3.10, `biblatex` is able to detect footnotes automatically with `beamer`, the warning will be gone.

`biblatex` needs to patch the `\@footnotetext` commands to include `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` to be able to detect if it is in a footnote or not.
The usual approach is just a `\patchcmd` to the respective macro. But `beamer` needs to do some clever stuff with its version of `\@footnotetext` called `\beamer@framefootnotetext` so that patching has to look a bit different.

The necessary code can be found in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/5169d2a64777090aa29d38df7543301f5c8b876b

The gist is that we had to use

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname beamerx@\string\beamer@framefootnotetext\endcsname
  {\color@begingroup}
  {\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}
  {\togglefalse{blx@tempa}}
  {}
```

instead of just `\patchmd{\beamer@framefootnotetext}`.