# How to force biblatex to patch footnotes when \footnotetext was redefined by some other package?

Tags: biblatex, linguex

`biblatex` issues the following warning when used with the `linguex` package.

```
Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex) Footnote detection will not work.
```

This is because the `linguex` redefines `\footnotetext` in order to support numbered examples in footnotes and endnotes.

However, redefining `\footnotetext` makes it impossible (difficult?) for `biblatex` to patch footnotes in order to support *ibid* and *ibidem* citations.

According to an answer ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108523/22435)), this is a warning we can safely ignore as long as we're not using an *ibid* citation style.

But what if a user wants to use both `linguex` and some *ibid* citation style? Is there a way to make biblatex override whatever has been done to `\footnotetext`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage
[
  backend = biber,
  style   = authoryear-ibid,
]
{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a working example, it is tough, but maybe load `linguex` thus: `\let\svfootnotetext\footnotetext\usepackage{linguex}\let\footnotetext\svfootnotetext`.  This will restore the definition of `\footnotetext` to that which preexisted the loading of `linguex`.

Comment: This won't work. `\let` works with a pointer to `\footnotetext`, whereas those packages redefine whatever that pointer points to.

Comment: `\let` does *not* work with a pointer, but makes an actual copy.  Now the problem may be that what gets changed is not `\footnotetext`, but subsidiary routine(s).  In that case, this procedure needs to be applied to the *actual* routine(s) that are changed by `linguex`.

Comment: You're right. It turns out that `linguex` redefines `\@footnotetext`. So, the following should go after loading it: `\makeatletter \let\@footnotetext\predefinedfootnotetext \makeatother`

Comment: But then you destroy the redefinition of linguex.

Comment: Well, unless `biblatex` finds out another way to patch footnotes, we need to choose between *ibid* footnotes or footnotes with numbered examples. I choose *ibid* footnotes.

Comment: Note that the footnote detection only really becomes important if you use `\footnote{... \cite{} ...}`; if you only use `\footcite` you should be fine. You should also be fine if you only ever cite in footnotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the best of both worlds:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[
  backend = biber,
  style   = authoryear-ibid,
]
{biblatex}
\usepackage{linguex}

\makeatletter
\let\linguex@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\let\@footnotetext\predefinedfootnotetext
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\predefinedfootnotetext\@footnotetext
  \let\@footnotetext\linguex@footnotetext
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\textheight}{5cm} % just to get a smaller image

\begin{document}

Lorem \cite{worman} ipsum\footcite{sigfridsson} dolor\footnote{\cite{sigfridsson}}

Text and text\footnote{A different example would be:
\ex. This is the first level of embedding 
  \a. This is the second level
  \b. This is still the second level, but:
    \a. This is the third level 
    \b. This is not the end. 
    \b. This is the end.\par}.

\end{document}
```

Explanation.

`linguex` lets `\predefinedfootnotetext` to be `\@footnotetext`; then it redefines `\@footnotetext` in terms of the original. However, when at begin document, `biblatex` tries to patch `\@footnotetext` and it fails. Thus we can provisionally restore the meaning of `\@footnotetext` for the patch and then reapply the redefinition by `linguex` when the patch has been done.

Make a feature request to the `biblatex` team so they also support `linguex`, which is quite easy as they just need to patch `\predefinedfootnotetext` in the case the package is loaded, just like they provide for some other case in which the command to patch is different.

[image]

Comment: I'm not following. When at begin document we let `\@footnotetext` be `\linguex@footnotetext`, why doesn't this override the patch that `biblatex` has just applied?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this works. Does it make any difference whether `biblatex` is loaded earlier than `linguex`, as your example, rather than later, as in mine?

Comment: @n.r. It shouldn't matter. Look at the redefinition of `\@footnotetext` performed by `linguex` and you'll understand why this works.

Comment: Now I see it. `\@footnotetext` will expand to, among other things, a `\predefinedfootnotetext` as modified by `biblatex`.

Comment: @n.r. Right. And the modification happens `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: Patched in biblatex 3.5

Comment: Tested. The patch works.

Answer (score 2):

You can restore the footnote detection capabilities with

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\@noftnotefalse\predefinedfootnotetext{\toggletrue{blx@footnote}#1}%
         \@noftnotetrue}
\makeatother
```

That will not get rid of the warning, though, but it can now be safely ignored.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage[backend = biber, style = authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\@noftnotefalse\predefinedfootnotetext{\toggletrue{blx@footnote}#1}%
         \@noftnotetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{worman} ipsum\footcite{sigfridsson} dolor\footnote{\cite{sigfridsson}}
\end{document}
```

gives

> <sup>1</sup> Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998.
>
> <sup>2</sup> ibid

in foonotes, while without the modification you'd get

> <sup>1</sup> Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998.
>
> <sup>2</sup> Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998.

Comment: What exactly does `blx@footnote` flag to `biblatex`?

Comment: @n.r. It is the toggle to check if we are in a footnote. If it is true `biblatex` knows that we are in a footnote. Some of the predefined commands already set the toggle accordingly (that's why `\footcite` works), but we need to set it to true within `\footcitetext` - here the patching comes in.

Comment: I wonder if this is the sole modification that `biblatex` makes on `\@footnotetext`. Because if it is, then there must be a more relaxed way to patch `\@footnotetext`, say, by merely prepending `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` to whatever `\@footnotetext` would expand to, and thus avoid unnecessarily breaking the *ibid* feature.

Comment: @n.r. As far as I can see `biblatex` only inserts `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` after `\color@begingroup` in `footnotetext`-like commands. I suppose one needs to make sure the grouping is right and that is why `biblatex` patches commands like it does right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get rid of `biblatex` warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext\predefinedfootnotetext
\makeatother

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}    
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

We revert `\@footnotetext` back to its standard definition using `\predefinedfootnotetext`, which is provided by `linguex` itself.

Notice, however, that in this way we'll no longer be able to use `linguex` in **footnotes**, and will need to resort to something like `enumerate` environments to get numbered examples in footnotes.